# Arrow function in string rendered item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

All,
I am struggling with the following code:

```
rowRenderer = (e) => {
    debugger;
    return e.data?.fileName ? 
        '<a class="documentLink" onclick={() => \'' + console.log('\'' + e.data.fileName + '\'') + '\'}>' + e.data.fileName + '</a>' : 
        e.data.name;
}
```

this prints the fileName in the console correctly but in the  tag the filename appears " 'undefined'}>file-sample_500kB.doc" - I understand that there is a problem with the escape but I am not able to see it
The above code is a just a test - the original code should be :

```
    rowRenderer = (e) => {
    debugger;
    return e.data?.fileName ? 
        '<a class="documentLink" onclick={() => this.downloadFileClickHandler(\'' + JSON.stringify(e.data) + '\')}>' + e.data.fileName + '</a>' : 
        e.data.name;
}
```

I want to call a function on button click

Comment: Try using literals templates instead of quotes, it makes the quote more readable and less prone to syntax errors

Comment: Why do you even need to do this with react?

Answer (score 0):

Your function just return a string because of you + strings. If you are using ReactJS you should return a component like:

```
rowRenderer = (e) => {
    return e.data?.fileName ? <a className={"documentLink"} onClick={() => console.log(e.data.fileName)} > {e.data.fileName}</a> : e.data.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

```
    rowRenderer = (params) => {
    return params.data?.fileName ?
        `<a class="documentLink" onClick="document.getElementById('download_${params.data.id}').click();">${params.data.name}</a>` :
        params.data.name;
}
```

and the rowRenderer is passed in optionalGridProps

```
            optionalGridProps={{
                autoGroupColumnDef: {
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        suppressCount: true,
                        innerRenderer: (param) => this.rowRenderer(param)
                    },
            }
```

And then I created a new column in the grid with "headerClass: 'emptyHeader'" and:

```
cellRendererFunction: (params) => {
                const rowContent = params.data;
                return (
                    <div id={`download_${rowContent.id}`} key={rowContent.id} className={'link hidden'} onClick={(e) => this.downloadFileClickHandler(e, rowContent)}>{rowContent.name}</div>
                );
            },
```